# What eBook conversions from HTML to Kindle and ePub scale best to 8MB input?

Tags: kindle, epub, calibre, kindlegen

I am working with Calibre and now, from the command line, know how to use convert-ebook to transform HTML source to Kindle and ePub output.

The operation is taking multiple minutes, possibly my fault in that I am working on an 8MB HTML input file.

What, if any, options do I have that will convert the HTML input faster?

How does KindleGen compare to Calibre in performance characteristics?